# Como puedo alinear elementos en un Navbar de Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Bien, lo primero es que he intentado por varios métodos que he encontrado en distintos post pero ninguno ha resultado.
Me gustaría saber como en la siguiente barra de navegación de Bootstrap 4 que voy a exponer podría alinear los dos botones 'Register' y 'Login' en la parte derecha de la barra de navegación y el resto de elementos a la izquierda ( donde están ahora ).
Por el momento he intentado bastantes métodos y ninguno da resultado.

Codigo:

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">YourSnailHouse</a>
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
       <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
           <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
       Dropdown link
           </a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu">
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
       </div>
       </li>
       <ul class="navbar-button">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
           <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" style="margin-left: 20px">Register</button>
       </ul>
   </ul>
   </nav>
```

Muchas gracias ante cualquier posible ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leyendo un poco sobre la documentacion del Grid system de Bootstrap, encontre que tal vez te puede funcionar utilizar la clase "row justify-content-between" que te muestro en un ejemplo, esta clase te desplegara el contenido justificado con un espacio intermedio entre las dos secciones que deseas dividir. Ej:

```
<div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-4">
      Columna del lado izquierdo
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      Columna del lado derecho
    </div>
</div>
```

Puedes encontrar mas informacion al respecto en:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment

Comment: Las clases para justificar no debería usarse para alinear elementos a la izquierda o derecha, considera ver: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/float/#classes

Comment: Tras haber estado probando distintas combinaciones con ese método tampoco consigo alinearlo, pero también me he dado cuenta que bootstrap no esta funcionando como debería en algunas ocasiones por lo que podría ser por eso, muchas gracias aun asi.